# How to bind ionic3-star-rating dynamic value into data object in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, data-binding

iam get some problems.
i have an dynamic form input of rating parameter, i try use ionic3-star-rating module; https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic3-star-rating. Package its work, but i cant bind dynamic value into my object.
 
 the code like this ; 
`input-scanner.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let dataP of dataParameter">
    <ion-row class="parameter-input">
        <ion-item text-center class="xgray">
            <h4 class="h-title">{{dataP.name}}</h4>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item no-padding text-center class="silver">
            <ionic3-star-rating activeIcon="star" defaultIcon="star-outline" activeColor="#e6821e" defaultColor="#404040" readonly="false" [rating]="0"> 
            </ionic3-star-rating> 
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-input">
            <ion-input type="text"  placeholder="Masukkan notes.." [(ngModel)]="dataP.notes"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
</div>
<button ion-button icon-only (click)="saveRecord(dataParameter)">
    <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

`input-scanner.ts`

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public events: Events,
    public toastCtrl : ToastController,
    public alCtrl : AlertController) {

    events.subscribe('star-rating:changed', (starRating) => 
      {
        this.bindRatingId(1,starRating)
```

// how can i get id ; (1) dynamic from my event click the ionic3-star-rating?

```
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getDataParameter();
  }
  bindRatingId(id,starRating){
    console.log(starRating);
  }
  getDataParameter(){
    var data = [
      {"name":"FIRE BOX. No.157","id":1,"rating":"","notes":""},
      {"name":"PIPA. No.158","id":2,"rating":"","notes":""},
      {"name":"FIRE BOX. No.158","id":3,"rating":"","notes":""},
    ];
    for(let v of data){
        this.dataParameter.push(v);
    }
  }
  saveRecord(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
```

when i click button saveRecord, the result is ;

```
[
  {"name":"FIRE BOX. No.157","id":1,"rating":"5","notes":"some input"},
  {"name":"PIPA. No.158","id":2,"rating":"","notes":""},
  {"name":"FIRE BOX. No.158","id":3,"rating":"","notes":"" }
]
```

the rating value not dynamically set into my object :(,
 because i set manual in the bindRatingId() just to set id=1 .
 How can i get dynamically value from ionic3-star-rating module ? when i try to add [(ngModel)] in attributee, i have an error code .
someone can help me please? thank you before it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oke guys. I have fix the problem right now, i only change the package ionic3-star-rating, into ionic2-rating module. Its work fine, with ngModel :)

Answer (score 0):

Please store the rating data type as a number and apply the below code.

```
<div *ngFor="let dataP of dataParameter">
        <ion-row class="parameter-input">
            <ion-item text-center class="xgray">
                <h4 class="h-title">{{dataP.name}}</h4>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item no-padding text-center class="silver">
                <ionic3-star-rating activeIcon="star" defaultIcon="star-outline" activeColor="#e6821e" defaultColor="#404040" readonly="false" [rating]="dataP.rating"> 
                </ionic3-star-rating> 
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="item-input">
                <ion-input type="text"  placeholder="Masukkan notes.." [(ngModel)]="dataP.notes"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-row>
    </div>
```

Comment: its same. Just change the view, not binding the data model :(